# pybbg module to exact Bloomberg data in python

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I just install the pybbg package throw git clone and python setup.py install. 
I already have the bloomberg api for windows

I try to run the examples code from the library and I keep have the message that : "pybbg has no attribute 'Pybbg'".

For example :

```
import unittest
import datetime
import pybbg

class TestPybbg(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_bds(self):
        tester = pybbg.Pybbg()
        data = tester.bdp('AAPL US Equity','PX_Last')
        print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: if you print out dir(pybbg) does it have any other similar attributes?

Comment: Thanks,I saw that I don't have pybbg_k but not pybbg. I change the code for pybbg_k. Im now able to run the code but I don't have any output. No "data" in the variable explorer...